# Two problems per page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment

I am making a problem worksheet. I want to put two problems per page, with the first one at the top of the page and the second one at the middle. Currently, I am manually adjusting it using

```
\vspace*
\newpage
```

every time I want to make a space between problems. Is there any convenient and clever way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add a minimal example of what you tried so far, thank you!

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Top cuestion
\vfill 
Bottom question
\vfill\newpage 
Top question on other page
\end{document}`

Comment: @Fran This was exactly what I wanted. Thanks.